# Windows forms application with database publishing

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, publishing

I'll try to keep the question simple and short - what are the best practices when publishing a windows forms application which is using a SQL Server database?

Using ClickOnce with prerequisites I can enforce SQL Server Express installation, but what if it's already installed? How do you build the connection string? How do you find the names of the instances of the server? What kind of authentication should be used - Windows or SQL? Can this process be automated or is user interaction inevitable?

Comment: surely there are plenty of examples about doing this the way you described. if your application is small and not supposed to have multiple clients and one database centralized somewhere in the network (as I guess from your description), you could also consider using SQL Server Mobile (embedded) which requires no setup and runs directly in-process with your application. Of course does not offer all features of SQL Express so really depends on your needs.

Comment: @DavidePiras Yes, I read about it, and it seems like a good solution, but SQL Server Mobile doesn't support triggers, and my database has quite a lot of them.

Comment: You can also use SQL lite/ slq ce if you really requires the database on the installation...

Comment: @Davide Piras It seems that SQL Server CE is the way to go. I got rid of the triggers and now all works like a charm. Thanks for the suggestion, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer since this is the way you decided to go anyway, glad to help :)

You could also consider using SQL Server Compact which requires no setup and runs directly in-process with your application. Of course does not offer all features of SQL Express so really depends on your needs.

Have a look at: [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876)

Note: if you could easily get rid of your triggers either you have cut functionalities or you got rid of things you do not really needed. I am old school and never use triggers, they are ofthen misused, seen people creating triggers just to set a default value in a column because did not know could have used the default.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, in this scenario I would say you would have to take into account the use of the database, if the database is connected up to a network which will support many users authentication would be needed and would inevitibly face some kind of user interaction.